# Performance of 2D array allocation

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I am wondering why allocation of a 2D int array at once (`new int[50][2]`) performs poorer than allocating separately, that is, execute `new int[50][]` first, then `new int[2]` one-by-one. Here is a non-professional benchmark code:

```
public class AllocationSpeed {

    private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 1000000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AllocationSpeed().run();
    }

    private void run() {
        measureSeparateAllocation();
        measureAllocationAtOnce();
    }

    private void measureAllocationAtOnce() {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
            allocateAtOnce();
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Allocate at once: " + stopwatch);
    }

    private int allocateAtOnce() {
        int[][] array = new int[50][2];
        return array[10][1];
    }

    private void measureSeparateAllocation() {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
        for (int i = 0; i < ITERATION_COUNT; i++) {
            allocateSeparately();
        }
        stopwatch.stop();
        System.out.println("Separate allocation: " + stopwatch);
    }

    private int allocateSeparately() {
        int[][] array = new int[50][];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = new int[2];
        }
        return array[10][1];
    }
}
```

I tested on 64 bit linux, these are the results with different 64 bit **oracle** java versions:

1.6.0_45-b06:

```
Separate allocation: 401.0 ms
Allocate at once: 1.673 s
```

1.7.0_45-b18

```
Separate allocation: 408.7 ms
Allocate at once: 1.448 s
```

1.8.0-ea-b115

```
Separate allocation: 380.0 ms
Allocate at once: 1.251 s
```

Just for curiosity, I tried it with OpenJDK 7 as well (where the difference is smaller):

```
Separate allocation: 424.3 ms
Allocate at once: 1.072 s
```

For me it's quite counter-intuitive, I would expect allocating at once to be faster.

Comment: I've tried it for different sizes and `Object[][]` and nothing changed. Either I'm really blind or you've found something interesting. Or the JIT outsmarts us and eliminates part of the work.

Answer (score 1):

***Absolute unbelievable.*** A benchmark source might suffer from optimizations, gc and JIT, but this?

Looking at the [java byte code instruction set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings):

- **anewarray** (+ 2 bytes indirect class index) for arrays of object classes (a = address)
- **newarray** (+ 1 byte for prinitive class) for arrays of primitive types
- **multianewarray**  (+ 2 bytes indirect class index) for multidimensional arrays

This leads one to suspect that multianewarray is suboptimal for primitive types.

Before looking further, I hope someone knows where we are misled.

Comment: The bytecode hardly ever tells us more about the speed than the source code as it's the JITC what makes the speed.

Comment: Do you mind expanding on why you think that `multianewarray` is suboptimal for primitives? I'm not quite following your deduction. As a side note, I personally believe that as is your answer would fit better as a comment, but it's probably not a big deal...

Comment: It seems that `multianew` has lost its immediate knowledge that the allocation is about primitives, as opposed to `newarray`. It might be doing something like `anewarray` for every `int[]`. But I do not claim that this is definitely so. In fact this would be a bad implementation.

Comment: Why would that implementation be bad? Wouldn't it be essentially equivalent to OP's code? First thing that came to mind as to why info on primitives is lost is that perhaps that was to deal with arbitrarily nested arrays, but I doubt that that is right...

Comment: but I just reproduced it with the same results

Answer (score 0):

The latter code's inner loop (with a `newarray`) is hit more times than the former code's `multianewarray`, so it probably hits C2 and gets subjected to escape analysis sooner. (Once that happens, the rows created by the latter code are allocated on the stack, which is faster than the heap *and* reduces the workload for the garbage collector.)

It's also possible that these JDK versions didn't actually *do* escape analysis on rows from a `multianewarray`, since a multidimensional array is more likely to exceed the size limit for a stack array.